# Setting custom HTML5 validity message property ignores pattern regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I'm using the pattern attribute in an HTML5 input. It works fine, until I add a custom message using setCustomValidity. All this is supposed to do is

> Sets the validationMessage property of an input element.

But instead my pattern is ignored. If I comment out the setCustomValidity, the pattern works.

HTML

```
<form>Country code:
    <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
</form>
```

JS

```
$('input').get(0).setCustomValidity("It's wrong");

$('input').on('input', function () {
    console.log($(this).prop('validity'));
    var valid = $(this).get(0).checkValidity();
    console.log(valid); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrtsz50s/

Comment: Please explain expected results in more detail. Docs state that element is assumed invalid when you use that method with a non empty string argument. You are over riding any other validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `reportValidity();` insted of `checkValidity();` and when you call the function clear the validity with an empty string first!

```
$('input').get(0).setCustomValidity("It's wrong");

$('input').on('input', function () {
    this.setCustomValidity('');//Add this!!
    console.log($(this).prop('validity'));
    var valid = $(this).get(0).reportValidity();//here
    console.log(valid); });
```

**edit**

Got it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrtsz50s/1/

Comment: Oh.. I thought I was setting the error message in the case that the input is valid. This is what I wanted http://jsfiddle.net/hrtsz50s/2/